# Spring portlet. Resource requests (.js, .css) handling

Tags: java, spring, portlet

Since version 3.0.4 of the Srpingframework it is possible to load resources with

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/>
```

No ResourceServlet is needed.
This works only when using the Spring's DispatcherServlet.
I am developing applications in a portlet environment and do use DispatcherPortlet instead.
Is it possible to make this new resource serving also available for DispatcherPortlet?
Or how can i do it when use DispatcherPortlet?

Answer (score 0):

Because of the nature of Portlet Application, CSS/JavaScript resources in Portlets is managed by dynamically adding elements to the `HEAD` section of the container Portal Page. JSR-286 defines facilities to this overriding the `doHeaders` method, you can see how Liferay Portal handles that in this [link](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Including+Javascript+Files+in+pages+and+portlets).

Be careful because this is an optional feature of the specification, so many Portlet Containers choose to not implement that functionality. Review your Product Documentation to follow the recommended approach.